# How to pass a string variable which has space characters to curl command in windows cmd

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

How to pass a string with whitespaces characters to a variable to curl command in windows cmd?

I have to pass a string variable that has white space characters to curl requests in windows cmd.
Below is the command.

```
set emailID="xxxx@gmail.com"
set openAPISpec="http://petstore/v2/swagger.json"
set licenseKey="ccc0e4-b000-491f-9d7b-7e59f9768"

set projectName="Online Banking REST API OmPf"

set MyDefault="dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyDefault"
set MyRoleAdmin="dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyRoleAdmin"
set MyRoleUser="dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyRoleUser"

curl -s --location --request POST "https://dev.ethicalcheck.qtech.ai/api/v1/scan" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{     \"openAPISpec\": \"%openAPISpec%\", \"email\": \"%emailID%\", \"licenseKey\": \"%licenseKey%\", \"projectName\": \"%projectName%\", \"headers\":[\"Authorization: Bearer %MyDefault%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleAdmin%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleUser%\"] }"
```

When I run the above command in windows cmd below is the response

```
curl -s --location --request POST "https://dev.ethicalcheck.qtech.ai/api/v1/scan" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{     \"openAPISpec\": \"%openAPISpec%\", \"email\": \"%emailID%\", \"licenseKey\": \"%licenseKey%\", \"projectName\": \"%projectName%\", \"headers\":[\"Authorization: Bearer %MyDefault%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleAdmin%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleUser%\"] }"


{"timestamp":"2022-10-19T03:03:39.094+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/api/v1/scan"}
```

The above command in windows CMD is working perfectly if the variable doesn't have whitespaces characters.

The same was the error I was getting in Linux bash, so I modified the above command accordingly to the Linux environment and it's working perfectly even for whitespaces characters in the variable.

Below is the working command in Linux if a variable has whitespaces characters in it.

```
export emailID="xxxx@gmail.com"
export openAPISpec="http://petstore/v2/swagger.json"
export licenseKey="ccc0e4-b000-491f-9d7b-7e59f9768"

export projectName="Online Banking REST API OmPf"

export MyDefault="dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyDefault"
export MyRoleAdmin="dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyRoleAdmin"
export MyRoleUser="dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyRoleUser"

curl -s --location --request POST "https://dev.ethicalcheck.qtech.ai/api/v1/scan" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{     "openAPISpec": "'${openAPISpec}'", "email": "'${emailID}'", "licenseKey": "'${licenseKey}'", "projectName": "'"${projectName}"'", "headers":["Authorization: Bearer '${MyDefault}'","Authorization: Bearer '${MyRoleAdmin}'","Authorization: Bearer '${MyRoleUser}'"] }'
```

Below is the actual thing that is working in Linux bash, I have added extra double quotations to handle whitespaces characters with the projectName variable, and with the email variable it's normal.

```
"projectName": "'"${projectName}"'"

"email": "'${emailID}'"
```

The same modification is not working in windows CMD or currently, I'm not able to figure out

```
#1 Tried to pass this way
\"projectName\": \"\'\"%projectName%\"\'\" 

# Command
curl -s --location --request POST "https://api.ethicalcheck.apisec.ai/api/v1/scan" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{     \"openAPISpec\": \"%openAPISpec%\", \"email\": \"%emailID%\", \"licenseKey\": \"%licenseKey%\", \"projectName\": \"\'\"%projectName%\"\'\", \"headers\":[\"Authorization: Bearer %MyDefault%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleAdmin%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleUser%\"] }"

# Response
{"timestamp":"2022-10-19T03:03:39.094+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/api/v1/scan"}


#2 Tried to pass this way
\"projectName\": \"\"%projectName%\"\" 

  # Command
    curl -s --location --request POST "https://api.ethicalcheck.apisec.ai/api/v1/scan" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{     \"openAPISpec\": \"%openAPISpec%\", \"email\": \"%emailID%\", \"licenseKey\": \"%licenseKey%\", \"projectName\": \"\"%projectName%\"\", \"headers\":[\"Authorization: Bearer %MyDefault%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleAdmin%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleUser%\"] }"

  # Response
    {"timestamp":"2022-10-19T03:03:39.094+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/api/v1/scan"}
```

So how do I pass a string with whitespaces characters as a variable to curl command in windows CMD?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to find another way to do your curl request.  Windows CMD curl is the worst.  I would rather install XAMPP and use PHP to do the curl.

Answer (score 0):

This link [why-is-no-string-output-with-echo-var-after-using-set-var-text-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386697/why-is-no-string-output-with-echo-var-after-using-set-var-text-command-i/26388460#26388460) helped in resolving the issue.
Thanks @Mofi

The below syntax worked for me.

```
set "emailID=xxxx@gmail.com"
set "openAPISpec=http://petstore/v2/swagger.json"
set "licenseKey=ccc0e4-b000-491f-9d7b-7e59f9768"

set "projectName=Online Banking REST API OmPf"

set "MyDefault=dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyDefault"
set "MyRoleAdmin=dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyRoleAdmin"
set "MyRoleUser=dXNlcjFAbmV0YmFua2luZy5pbzphZG1pbjEyMyRoleUser"


curl -s --location --request POST "https://dev.ethicalcheck.qtech.ai/api/v1/scan" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{     \"openAPISpec\": \"%openAPISpec%\", \"email\": \"%emailID%\", \"licenseKey\": \"%licenseKey%\", \"projectName\": \"%projectName%\", \"headers\":[\"Authorization: Bearer %MyDefault%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleAdmin%\", \"Authorization: Bearer %MyRoleUser%\"] }"
```